# Reduce redundant variable declaration in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, variable-declaration

In order to save space and reduce redundancy in Java. Is it okay to do

```
public static double a, b, c = 0.0;
```

instead of

```
public static double a = 0.0;
public static double b = 0.0;
public static double c = 0.0;
```

? Also if the variables have different values, is it okay to do

```
public static double a = 0.0, b = 1.0, c = 2.0;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java one line variable declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117500/java-one-line-variable-declaration)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202818/initializing-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-java

Comment: Considering that this syntactical sugar goes away at compile time... it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
public static double a = 0.0, b = 0.0, c = 0.0;
```

This way they are equivalent.
Otherwise, you rely on default initialization that is, of course, as if you had assigned `0.0` for a `double`, but is it is usually considered bad practice.